# Error while saving video using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv

Consider:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('captured.mp3', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 640))

while(cam.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('e'):
        break
cam.release()
out.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting an error while saving this video, like "Video type not supported". But I have tried all the combinations of file type. Still the video saved is of 0 KB.

Comment: Why are you trying to write video frames to an audio file (`.mp3`)?

Comment: Does this help? Change this `out=cv2.VideoWriter('captured.mp3'` to `out=cv2.VideoWriter('captured.mp4'`

Answer (score 2):

1. You're missing parentheses after out.release.
2. '.mp3' is typically used for audio files, while '.mp4' is used for video files.
3. It is important to set the 'VideoWriter' resolution to the camera resolution.
4. the MJPG codec isn't supported for the '.mp4' format, so you have two options - change the fourcc codec (for example, to 'H264'), or change the video format to '.avi'.

option 1:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
w = int(cam.get(3))
h = int(cam.get(4))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('captured.mp4', fourcc, 20, (w, h))

while cam.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break
    
cam.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

option 2:

```
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
w = int(cam.get(3))
h = int(cam.get(4))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('captured.avi', fourcc, 20, (w, h))

while cam.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('e'):
        break

cam.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```